# Finding out user with which chef-client is run

Tags: chef-infra

Inside the recipe , I want to use the username and password of the user with which chef-client has started the current run of the recipe. Is there any way to achieve this using any of the chef/node or ohai attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Ohai sets a current_user attribute:

```
$ ohai > ohai.json
$ jq {current_user} ohai.json
{
  "current_user": "mark"
}
```